# Pandas dividing hourly indexed df by daily indexed df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have huge a huge df (1 billion lines) of tick data.I'm interested in volume data. I'm calculating hourly sums with grouby/resample. I'd like to express these sums a percentage of the daily sum. I can calculate the daily sums with groupby/resample. My question is can how can i divide the hourly sums by the daily sums without resampling the daily values to hourly and forward filling. If i divide the hourly df by the daily, does pandas broadcast according to index? Thanks.

```
volume=volume.resample('H',label='right',closed='right').sum()
daily_total=volume.resample('D',label='Left',closed='right').sum()
volume=volume/daily_total # ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Numpy Option for faster results:**

Get the hourly volume to a numpy array:

```
hourly_vol = stock_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H', level=0)).sum()['qty'].to_numpy()
```

Get 24h multiple ticks... in my case:

```
h = hourly_vol[22:-16]
```

Now we got (24 * n) rows, get data into 24 dimensions rows:

```
a = h.to_numpy().reshape(-1,24)
```

Get the total volume in each day:

```
dsum = a.sum(axis=1)
```

Broadcast to a 24 dimension array:

```
b = np.array([dsum]*24).transpose()  # maybe this get a while
```

Get results:

```
result = a/b
```

And reshape for inserting in the original Dataframe:

```
result = result.reshape(240)
```

Note: remember in this case, I drop 16 and 22 other rows at the begining, then I need to inser result in a an original dataframe:

```
df.iloc[22:-16]['result'] = result
```

***Pandas Solution (not good for very big datasets):***

**Pandas Short answer:**

```
daily_vol = stock_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', level=0)).sum()['qty']
hourly_vol = stock_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H', level=0)).sum()['qty']
totals_col = daily_vol[pd.date_range("2020-06-04 02:00", "2020-06-15 15:00", freq="60min")].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
result = hourly_vol/totals_col
```

**Explanation:**
We got tick data like this, but need time index (example from binance.com BTC/USDT):

```
df.head(3):
    id          price       qty         quoteQty    time                    isBuyerMaker isBestMatch    grouper     tick_rule   dollar_bt   abs_theta
0   334736000   9663.87     0.015233    147.209732  2020-06-04 02:37:29.688     False   True    0.0     0.0     -147.209732     2.557702e+08
1   334736001   9663.51     0.004417    42.683724   2020-06-04 02:37:29.805     True    True    0.0     0.0     -42.683724  2.557701e+08
2   334736002   9663.73     0.016810    162.447301  2020-06-04 02:37:29.813     False   True    0.0     1.0     162.447301  2.557703e+08
```

Get time index:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms')
stock_df = df.set_index('time')
```

Daily volume totals:

```
daily_vol = stock_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', level=0)).sum()['qty']

time
2020-06-04    53696.704657
2020-06-05    47788.050050
2020-06-06    32752.950893
2020-06-07    57952.848385
2020-06-08    40664.664125
2020-06-09    46024.001289
2020-06-10    47130.762982
2020-06-11    94418.984730
2020-06-12    50119.066932
2020-06-13    27759.784851
2020-06-14    30055.506608
2020-06-15    57688.820941
Freq: D, Name: qty, dtype: float64
```

Hourly volume totals:

```
hourly_vol = stock_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H', level=0)).sum()['qty']

time
2020-06-04 02:00:00     447.253335
2020-06-04 03:00:00    1631.115302
2020-06-04 04:00:00    1703.933586
2020-06-04 05:00:00    1165.990115
2020-06-04 06:00:00    1441.345409
                          ...     
2020-06-15 11:00:00    2492.983349
2020-06-15 12:00:00    1971.762135
2020-06-15 13:00:00    3724.376480
2020-06-15 14:00:00    4531.290738
2020-06-15 15:00:00     811.775574
Freq: H, Name: qty, Length: 278, dtype: float64
```

To get pct in an hour over a day, we need to get daily total in each hour row after other calculations:

```
totals_col = daily_vol[pd.date_range("2020-06-04 02:00", "2020-06-15 15:00", freq="60min")].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')

2020-06-04 02:00:00    47788.050050
2020-06-04 03:00:00    47788.050050
2020-06-04 04:00:00    47788.050050
2020-06-04 05:00:00    47788.050050
2020-06-04 06:00:00    47788.050050
                           ...     
2020-06-15 11:00:00    57688.820941
2020-06-15 12:00:00    57688.820941
2020-06-15 13:00:00    57688.820941
2020-06-15 14:00:00    57688.820941
2020-06-15 15:00:00    57688.820941
Freq: 60T, Name: qty, Length: 278, dtype: float64
```

And the percentage of an hour in a day of the volumne can be calculated:

```
hourly_vol/totals_col

time
2020-06-04 02:00:00    0.009359
2020-06-04 03:00:00    0.034132
2020-06-04 04:00:00    0.035656
2020-06-04 05:00:00    0.024399
2020-06-04 06:00:00    0.030161
                         ...   
2020-06-15 11:00:00    0.043214
2020-06-15 12:00:00    0.034179
2020-06-15 13:00:00    0.064560
2020-06-15 14:00:00    0.078547
2020-06-15 15:00:00    0.014072
Freq: H, Name: qty, Length: 278, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i was searching for a way of doing it without resampling into hourly and forward filling. As the datasets are huge it already takes quite a lot of memory and a long time.

Comment: Oh... sorry... let me think in a numpy solution... or even numba

Comment: volume=volume/daily_total[volume.index.day] would this work you think?

Comment: I think the faster way (withot using numba coda) is the numpy approach.

Comment: Thanks the idea of reshaping into 24 columns is good and i'll do it. But i'm pretty sure you don't need to broadcast b manually numpy does by itself : perc= a/a.sum(axis=1)